# Separating words in a file with commas Java?

Tags: java

This is what I have 
no error is displayed but it doesn't run please tell me what the problem is
Do i have to import something else???
The file is a paragraph from a book

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Unique {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public void add(String fileName) throws Exception {    
        File inFile = new File("ReadThis.txt");
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String word = scanner.next() ;                     
            word = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");         
            words.add(word) ;                                  
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your main method doesn't contain any instruction. So nothing happens. And even if it did call the add() method, this method reads the file and stores strings in a list, but it dosn't do anything with that list. It's just an expensive noop.

Answer (score 1):

The entry point of your code is empty.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

The behavior you describe is exactly what this code does: **nothing**.

You'll have to insert the code you want to run into the `main-method` in order to get it running. E.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Unique().add("someFile");
}
```